# querying polymorphic relationship

Tags: mysql

I'm not really expert in backend. I have here some columns of `notification` table which has been used by a polymorphic relationship in Laravel.

```
+----+------------------+----------------+
| id | sendto_type      |   sendto_id    | 
+----+------------------+----------------+
|  1 | App\User         |              1 |  
|  2 | App\User         |              2 |   
|  3 | App\Station      |              1 | 
|  4 | App\Station      |              2 | 
+----+------------------+----------------+
```

I want to query only from `sendto_type` column that has `App\User` attribute on it. Is it possible? and if yes, how would I do that.

These  are some columns from the users table which I referred on `App\User`

```
+----+------------------+----------------+
| id | firstname        |   lastname     | 
+----+------------------+----------------+
|  1 | dummy            |    imdummy     |  
|  2 | dummy2           |    imdummy2    |   
|  3 | dummy3           |    imdummy4    | 
|  4 | dummy4           |    imdummy3    | 
+----+------------------+----------------+
```

I tried querying `SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE sendto_type = "App\User"`. It was successful but returns no result. Please help

Comment: Change double quotes `"` by `'` single quotes. `'App\User'`

Answer (score 0):

your query should work in mysql

> ```
> CREATE TABLE notification (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `sendto_type` VARCHAR(11),
>   `sendto_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO notification
>   (`id`, `sendto_type`, `sendto_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'App\User', '1'),
>   ('2', 'App\User', '2'),
>   ('3', 'App\Station', '1'),
>   ('4', 'App\Station', '2');
>
> CREATE TABLE user (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `firstname` VARCHAR(6),
>   `lastname` VARCHAR(8)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO user
>   (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'dummy', 'imdummy'),
>   ('2', 'dummy2', 'imdummy2'),
>   ('3', 'dummy3', 'imdummy4'),
>   ('4', 'dummy4', 'imdummy3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT n.id,u.* FROM notification n inner JOIN user u ON  u.id = n.sendto_id WHERE `sendto_type` = "App\User"
> ```
>
> ```
> id | id | firstname | lastname
> -: | -: | :-------- | :-------
>  1 |  1 | dummy     | imdummy 
>  2 |  2 | dummy2    | imdummy2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f51f4cda56f6ae16b8d902a1d8f912b)*